# Submit radio button on contact form

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Using a very simple PHP contact form, need to add the chosen radio button option to the form.

All other fields work but cannot collect which radio button was chosen.

This is the contact form:

```
<label for="name" class="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" class="required"> 

<label for="companyname" class="companyname">Company Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="companyname" id="companyname" value="" class="required">

<label for="quality1">1</label> <input type="radio" id="quality1" name="quality" value="">
<label for="quality2">2</label> <input type="radio" id="quality2" name="quality" value="">
<label for="quality3">3</label> <input type="radio" id="quality3" name="quality" value="">
<label for="quality4">4</label> <input type="radio" id="quality4" name="quality" value="">  

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="formButton" id="submit" value="Submit">
```

Then this is submitted through javascript with other fields which work.

```
$(function() {
$('.error').hide();

$(".formButton").click(function() {
  
  $('.error').hide();
    
  var name = $("input#name").val();
  
  var companyname = $("input#companyname").val();
  
  var quality = $("input#quality").val();

  var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&companyname=' + companyname + '&quality=' + quality;
    //alert (dataString);return false;
    
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "contact-form-to-email.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
    $('#contactFormArea').html("<div id='submitMessage'></div>");
    $('#submitMessage').html("<p>Thank you.</p>")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(1000, function() {
      $('#submitMessage');
    });
  }
 });
return false;
});
});
```

PHP Form submission from above.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
$nameErr = ' ';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$companyname = $_POST['companyname'];
$quality = $_POST['quality'];

$email_from = 'no-reply@email.co.uk';
$email_subject = "Form";
$email_body = "Form info \n". 
" \n".
"Name: $name \n".
" \n".
"Company Name: $companyname \n".
" \n".
"Quality Of Service: $quality \n".
" \n".


$to = "info@email.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
?>
```

I need to show only the chosen radio button from the group of 'quality' fields.

Answer (score 1):

When a radio button is selected on the PHP side you will have `$_POST['input_name']` equals the selected input value. In your case all radio button have an empty string as value.
Your code should be something like that

```
<label for="quality1">1</label> <input type="radio" id="quality1" name="quality" value="1">
<label for="quality2">2</label> <input type="radio" id="quality2" name="quality" value="2">
<label for="quality3">3</label> <input type="radio" id="quality3" name="quality" value="3">
<label for="quality4">4</label> <input type="radio" id="quality4" name="quality" value="4">
```

Comment: Thanks, i've updated this but still getting a blank field on the submission.

Comment: I've missed another error… `var quality = $("input#quality")` is undefined. You must use instead, for example, `var quality = $('[name="quality"]:selected')`